# SQL Server : UPDATE statement has no effect

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Inside SQL Server 2008 Management Studio I am running the following queries:

```
UPDATE [DatabaseName].[dbo].[Addresses] 
SET Suburb = 'PERTH' 
WHERE Suburb = 'LAUNCESTON'
```

and then

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * 
FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[Addresses] 
WHERE Suburb = 'LAUNCESTON'
```

The first query tells me that 86 rows were affected, the second query gives me 86 results. I have also tried the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * 
FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[Addresses] with (nolock) 
WHERE Suburb = 'LAUNCESTON'
```

but it gives me the same results. If I use SQL Server Management Studio's "Edit top 200 rows" feature, as soon as I leave the cell I've edited, it reverts back to what it was.

What is going on?

Comment: If you add a COMMIT statement after your UPDATE command, does that make the changes stick?

Comment: i'm not entirely sure how to do that... i just added `begin transaction;` before it and `commit transaction;` after it - that made no difference

Comment: Are there any triggers on the dbo.Addresses table that could be preventing the updates?

Comment: Yes! That was the problem. If you submit that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There could be triggers on the dbo.Addresses table that are preventing the updates.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts to help with debugging this.

1. Look for any UPDATE triggers (either AFTER or INSTEAD OF) on the Addresses table that might be changing your expected results.
2. Run a SQL Profiler trace on your database server so you can capture the query being passed in on that side.